# Is there a secure way to share a secret key to another entity without a use of PKI

Tags: asymmetric, secret-sharing

My concern is with resource constrained devices with limited resources to perform verification of signatures e.g. RSA signature. What I know is that the asymmetric keys are use to determine that the symmetric key is coming from legitimate source.

Since, some of the IoT devices lack resources for such computation. What can be another way to share the symmetric key.

Comment: I'm guessing thumb drives aren't an option?

Comment: Thanks, any over the air solution?

Comment: +1 This is certainly one of the big challenges in IoT security!